# Run javascript document from PowerShell script

Tags: 2013, javascript, powershell, jquery

We want to create PowerShell script that will call javascript document, stored on our server. PowerShell script would be started on Task Scheduler at some time we define.
Javascript script calls jquery scripts like **jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min**, **bootstrap.min**, **jquery-2.2.4.min**.
Script is about checking some values in one of our list's columns.
If anyone can share example or suggestion where to check it.

I don't ask for a solution or "How to do it", just suggestion if this is possible and link to examples would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: As the below answer says, it would be a lot easier to just check the desired values with powershell and perform some action in there.  Powershell can pretty much do everything javascript can do through the CSOM.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is possible to:

- Create a page/view with all the scripts
- Have PowerShell using PhantomJs, Selenium or simular to:

  - Login
  - Load page
  - Wait for some sign of execution complete
  - Collect result

But I can't imagine it not being a lot more work than implementing the functionality of the script in PowerShell